# Ctx.drawImage is not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

I'm having troubles with load an image into the canvas, I've read every question about the same topic but I don't get a solution, clearly my problem is  that draw.Image doesn't work. Please can you give any help I'm really frustated. :C. Here a piece of my code...

```
fractnow();
function fractnow(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload=function(){
        ctx.drawImage(image, (image.width)/2,(image.height)/2,(image.width)/2,(image.height)/2);
};
image.src='C:/Users/Diego Goicochea/Desktop/fractal/fotolarge.png';
```

};

Comment: Firstly, using a file protocol for the image means it "tainted" and subject to the same origin policy, you should serve that image from the webserver the page is on. Secondly, the second and third argument is the top left corners X and Y position, and you're setting it that to the height and width of the image, are you sure the canvas is big enough, and that didn't want those to be just zero, as in place the image at the top left of the canvas.

Comment: Yes you were right it was a problem of dimensions, but I've run this in Microsoft Edge and it was perfectly. The same with the crossorigin problem. Is that a Google bug or something ?

Comment: @adeneo tainted content is only a problem if there are attempts to access the data directly. Rendering will not be affected.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't render, just that it would be tainted, and that one should serve images from the same origin, assuming the image is loaded into a canvas for some reason other than just displaying it.